# Evaluating series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(n^{1/n}-1-\frac{\log n}{n} \right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, riemann-zeta

This is similar to my recent question, but probably more interesting. What can we say about this slowly converging series:

$$S=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(n^{1/n}-1-\frac{\log n}{n} \right)$$

We can rewrite it as a double sum:

$$S=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\log^k n}{k!~n^k}$$

Or express through zeta derivatives at integer points:

$$S=\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{| \zeta^{(k)}(k) |}{k!}$$

Using the integral expression for zeta derivatives I obtained yesterday* and exchanging integration and summation, we can claim:

$$S=\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(k-1)^{k+1}}+$$

$$+ \frac{1}{i} \int_0^{\infty } \frac{dt}{\exp (2 \pi  t)-1} \left((1-i t)^{\frac{1}{1-i t}}-(1+i t)^{\frac{1}{1+i t}}-\frac{\log (1-i t)}{1-i t}+\frac{\log (1+i t)}{1+i t}  \right)$$

This gives us the following numerical value:

> $$S=1.0613654466259454755053404842148725835597350221360 \ldots$$

Directly evaluating the series in Mathematica is hard, but it gives an approximately the same value $1.06136544662594547550535127514661 \ldots$.

> **Questions:**
>
> - Is my numerical value correct? What other methods can we use to check? Euler-Maclaurin doesn't seem to work well, mostly because the integral is not nice eihter.

(The original version of this question contained a mistake, the corrected integral expression gives the same value as numerical summation for the first several digits, but I would still like to know more correct digits).

> - Is there a way to obtain a nicer integral expression for the series?

---

$*$ $$\zeta^{(n)}(s)=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(s-1)^{n+1}}- \\ +\frac{1}{i} \int_0^{\infty } \frac{dt}{e^{2 \pi  t}-1} \left(\frac{(1+i t)^s}{\left(1+t^2\right)^s} \log ^n\left(\frac{1+i t}{1+t^2}\right)-\frac{(1-i t)^s }{\left(1+t^2\right)^s}\log ^n\left(\frac{1-i t}{1+t^2}\right) \right)$$

Comment: One more interesting problem coming from you !

Comment: pari/gp works well here too ($400$ digits with 'sumpos' of the initial series) :   1.0613654466259454755053404842148725835597350221358618343344372665366249820644336475734133874799400179423862733855106418722013685910942224634349476494897308379376440758396655773135394342404297464644060406424661426990005956684805152253466825286491420195776758335443582941087449302166127353820520374442373405943540609904420380955614949737106583511032985527570241452884139528625349313953662387400016279560525

Comment: @RaymondManzoni, thank you, now I see that almost all of my digits for the modified series were correct. I definitely need to learn how to use pari/gp

Comment: Since $|\zeta^{(k)}(k)| \sim \exp(-1.004564461\,k)$  (observed experimentally, and many more digits are possible for the constant), the third formula presented is by far numerically superior.  I did look for a formula, but I don't see how an integral can beat it.

Comment: @skbmoore, can we explicitly find the error term (terms) for this approximation? Would you also be able to provide a reference for it? If you could elaborate in an answer, I would gladly accept it

Comment: I haven't seen the sum before, so no reference.  Because the series alternates, the error term is bounded by the last neglected term in a truncated sum, which will be very tiny, $\exp(-\kappa n)/n! $ where $\kappa$ was approximated to be 1.004564461.  Note that I don't have a proof that $|\zeta^{(k)}(k)|$ asymptotes in this manner, just numerical evidence.  It would be interesting to have a proof and see if $\kappa$ relates to other constants.

Comment: @ Yuriy S. Sorry, the sum doesn't alternate, so the simple error estimate is wrong.  I was looking at the alternating variant of your sum.

Comment: I've since sketched a proof of $\kappa = -\log(\log(3)/3) .$